# Translating SQL to LINQ with Group By and max

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm trying to write this SQL in LINQ, but I've gotten stuck.
This is the SQL:

```
select sc.screen_control_id screenControlId, s.screen_name screenName, c.control_name controlName, sc.width, sc.position, 
case when max(pp.permision_id) > 0 then 1 else 0 end display
from ui_screen_control sc
join ui_screen s on sc.screen_id = s.screen_id
join ui_control c on sc.control_id = c.control_id
join ui_screen_control_action sca on sc.screen_control_id = sca.screen_control_id
join auth_action_permissiongroup ap on sca.action_id = ap.action_id
join auth_permissiongroup_permission pp on ap.permissiongroup_id = pp.permissiongroup_id
join auth_user_action_permissiongroup_permission uapp on pp.permissiongroup_permission_id = uapp.permissiongroup_permission_id
where uapp.user_id = 5472
group by sc.screen_control_id, s.screen_name, c.control_name, sc.width, sc.position
```

I've tried this LINQ but no luck:

```
from sca in db.ui_screen_control_action
join ap in db.auth_action_permissiongroup on sca.action_id equals ap.action_id
from uapp in db.auth_user_action_permissiongroup_permission
where
  uapp.user_id == 5472
group new {sca.ui_screen_control, sca.ui_screen_control.ui_screen, sca.ui_screen_control.ui_control, uapp.auth_permissiongroup_permission} by new {
  sca.ui_screen_control.screen_control_id,
  sca.ui_screen_control.ui_screen.screen_name,
  sca.ui_screen_control.ui_control.control_name,
  width = (int?)sca.ui_screen_control.width,
  position = (int?)sca.ui_screen_control.position
} into g
select new {
  screenControlId = g.Key.screen_control_id,
  screenName = g.Key.screen_name,
  controlName = g.Key.control_name,
  width = (int?)g.Key.width,
  position = (int?)g.Key.position,
  display = 
  g.Max(p => p.uapp.auth_permissiongroup_permission.permision_id) > 0 ? 1 : 0
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from sc in db.ui_screen_control
join s in db.ui_screen on sc.screen_id equals s.screen_id
join c in db.ui_control on sc.control_id equals c.control_id
join sca in db.ui_screen_control_action on sc.screen_control_id equals sca.screen_control_id
join uapp in db.auth_user_action_permissiongroup_permission on sca.action_id equals uapp.action_id
where uapp.user_id == user.user_id
group new
{
 uapp.auth_permissiongroup_permission.permision_id
}
by new
{
 sc.screen_control_id,
 s.screen_name,
 c.control_name,
 sc.width,
 sc.position
}
into g
select new 
{
 screenControlId = g.Key.screen_control_id,
 screenName = g.Key.screen_name,
 controlName = g.Key.control_name,
 width = g.Key.width,
 position = g.Key.position,
 display = g.Min(p => p.permision_id) > 0 ? 1 : 0,
 required = false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to group it, you should just be able to use `Any` and do something like this:

```
db.ui_screen_control.Select(sc => 
    new {
         screenControlId = sc.screen_control_id,
         screenName = sc.ui_screen.screen_name,
         controlName = sc.ui_control.control_name,
         sc.width,
         sc.position,
         display = sc.ui_screen_control_actions
                    .auth_action_permissiongroup
                    .auth_permissiongroup_permission
                    .auth_user_action_permissiongroup_permission
                    .Any(uapp => uapp.user_id == 5472)
    });
```

`display` would then be a boolean, if you wanted a 1/0 still use something like `.Any(uapp => uapp.user_id == 5472) ? 1 : 0` instead.

Without seeing your model, I don't think you need to use `(int?)` and cast things, the EF should figure out nullable ints itself unless your model has been incorrectly setup when compared to the DB.

Comment: I like your idea, but I need the minimun value of all permissions assigned to a user. If the minimum value is 0 display == 0 else display == 1. I've tryed something like your approach, but couldn't get only one value. Finally I've done a grouping with a Minimun and is working well. And yes, you are wright, no need for (int?). Thanks anyway.

Comment: That's not what the code you posted does. It finds if any have a permission greater than 1 and if they do returns 1. You can easily do that instead thought, replace the `Any` with `.Where(uapp => uapp.user_id == 5472).Min(p => p.permision_id)`

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong on the requierement when posted. The problem is my navigation properties don't work like in your example. I can't concatenate more than one each time so I have to reselect. I could make joins as lambda expressions, but I find much more readable the query like syntax than lamda one for joins.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the line

```
from uapp in db.auth_user_action_permissiongroup_permission
```

This will probably do something like a cross join whereas your original sql would suggest you need something like

```
join pp   in db.auth_permissiongroup_permission             on ap.permissiongroup_id            equals pp.permissiongroup_id
join uapp in db.auth_user_action_permissiongroup_permission on pp.permissiongroup_permission_id equals uapp.permissiongroup_permission_id
```